# Why do I get errors in this Java method?

Tags: java, sorting, methods

I have to use this exact method "public static double[][] sortRows(double[][] m) {"

I did the block of code under it in a separate class and it was under the main method (forgot to change that) and it spoiled the whole thing. Where did I go wrong?

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class demo8{

public static double[][] sortRows(double[][] m) {
    double[][] result = new double[m.length][m[0].length];
        //create an int array
        double[] i1 = new double[] {0.15, 0.875, 0.375};
        System.out.print("1st array : ");
        Arrays.sort(i1);
        for(int index=0; index < i1.length ; index++)
          System.out.print("  "  + i1[index]);



        double[] i2 = new double[]{0.55, 0.005,0.225};
        Arrays.sort(i2);
        System.out.print('\n' + "2nd array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i2.length ; index++)
            System.out.print("  " + i2[index]);


        double[] i3 = new double[]{0.30, 0.12, 0.4};
        Arrays.sort(i3);
        System.out.print('\n' + "3nd array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i3.length ; index++)
          System.out.print("  "  + i3[index]);


      }
      }
```

Comment: you need a return statement

Answer (score 1):

`public static double[][]` with this you are saying that your method will return an object of the type `double[][]` however you do not have a `return` statement.

If you do not need to return any object at all, change the method to `void`

```
public static void sortRows(double[][] m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not Completely sure what you are asking but with any method that does not contain void you need a return statement.

Either change the method to void or add a return statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html